# C++ Creating a Book store, syntax error

Tags: c++, string, pointers, syntax-error, purchase-order

The error I am receiving there is `C3867 'Member::getMN': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member'`. Same error for getID,nBks,cost and tcost.

Asking for customers last name and ID number, then the number of books they want and asking for the cost of that book. Must show all info. Not sure where my error really is.

```
#ifndef MEMBER_H
#define MEMBER_H
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// define the class members and member function prototypes here
class Member 
{
private:
    string MemberName;//customer name
    string MemberID;//customer id
    int numBooks=0;//number of books
    double PurchaseAmt=0;//cost of books

public:
    void setMN(string);
    void setmID(string);
    void setnBks(int);
    void setcost(double);
    string getMN() const;
    string getID()const;
    int nBks()const;
    double cost()const;//cost of a book
    double tcost()const;
};
#endif

#include "member.h"   // Needed for the member class
#include <iostream>      // Needed for cout
#include <cstdlib>       // Needed for the exit function
using namespace std;

void Member::setMN(string name)//string size for membername
{   if (name.size() < 12)
        MemberName = name.substr(0, 12);
    else
    {
        cout << "Invalid Member ID\n";
        system("pause");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

void Member::setmID(string ID)//string size for MemberID
{   if (ID.size() < 5)
        MemberID = ID.substr(0,5);
    else
    {
        cout << "Invalid Member ID\n";
        system("pause");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

}
void Member::setnBks(int num)//check for number of books
{   if (num > 0)
        numBooks = num;
    else
    {
        cout << "Invalid book count, must be over 0.\n";
        system("pause");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

void Member::setcost(double amount)//check for cost of the book.
{   if (amount > 0)
        PurchaseAmt = amount;
    else
    {
        cout << "Invalid cost, can not be less then 0.\n";
        system("pause");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}


string Member::getMN() const
{   return MemberName;
}

string Member::getID() const
{   return MemberID;
}

int Member::nBks() const
{   return numBooks;
}

double Member::cost() const
{   return PurchaseAmt;
}

double Member::tcost() const//getting the total cost of the book(s)
{   return numBooks * numBooks;

}

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include "member.h"  // Needed for Member class

using namespace std;

void getinfo(Member&);
void display(Member);

int main()
{
    Member books;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
} // end main

//this function returns member name and id, also number of books and the cost.
  // this function displays the book store's data.
void getinfo(Member& x)
{
    string MemberName, MemberID;
    int numBooks;
    double PurchaseAmt;

    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

    cout << "What is the members last name, must be under 12 char?\n";
    cin >> MemberName;
    x.setMN(MemberName);

    cout << "What is the members ID, must be under 5 int?\n";
    cin >> MemberID;
    x.setmID(MemberID);

    cout << "How many books?\n";
    cin >> numBooks;
    x.setnBks(numBooks);

    cout << "How much does each book cost?\n";
    cin >> PurchaseAmt;
    x.setcost(PurchaseAmt);

} // end getting information.

void display(Member x)
{
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
    cout << "The member's last name is : " << x.getMN << endl;
    cout << "The member's ID is : " << x.getID << endl;
    cout << "The number of books bought are : " << x.nBks << endl;
    cout << "The cost per book is : " << x.cost << endl;
    cout << "The total is : " << x.tcost << endl;

}
```

Comment: When posting questions about errors, try to minimize the code to just the relevant parts (preferably create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us), and also mark out the lines with the errors in the source you show (with e.g. a comment in the code). And the compiler will tell you *exactly* where it finds the error, it will always show the file-name and the line-number, and sometimes even the function name.

Comment: Will do, I'm sorry about the large amount of Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just forgot the () after the method name

```
void display(Member x)
{
  cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
  cout << "The member's last name is : " << x.getMN() << endl;
  cout << "The member's ID is : " << x.getID() << endl;
  cout << "The number of books bought are : " << x.nBks() << endl;
  cout << "The cost per book is : " << x.cost() << endl;
  cout << "The total is : " << x.tcost() << endl;

}
```